# Angular 2 material mat-select calling multiple times

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using angular material . When I use onSelectionChange, its calling multiple times when page loading or when I change the selection. Can some one please help me.

```
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-select id="stateSelect" name="stateSelect" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="State Select" [(ngModel)]="myModel.state" required>
     <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateState($event)" *ngFor="let state of stateList" [value]="state.code">
       {{ state.value }}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   <mat-error>State is required</mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>

 // In my ts file
 updateState(event: any) {
   // my code
 }
```

I have used event.isUserInput to check true for false, But still some times its entering into condition without any selection. Some one please help me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested the following code yet, but I think you can use the select and option tags in this way:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select id="stateSelect" name="stateSelect" class="form-control" 
      placeholder="State Select" [(ngModel)]="myModel.state" (selectionChange)="updateState($event)" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of stateList" [value]="state.code">
      {{ state.value }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error>State is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Use **selectionChange** event in mat-select instead **onSelectionChange** in mat-option. Refer to material [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I tried this one too, but not calling updateState() method

Comment: I tried the code and it worked, remember the event is selectionChange.  I tested with Angular 5.2.

Comment: I was misplaced selectionChange in my code. I used in mat-option instead of mat-select. Now its working. Thanks

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend answer of @4ndt3s. ( To prevent same selection, [compareWith](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/select/api))

Event value of `onLangChange($event)` has a value for indicate panel open or not.
That is correct.
So, if you need allow same option selected,
Refer this, [Trigger event on re-selecting same value on mat-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286795/trigger-event-on-re-selecting-same-value-on-mat-select).

[Demo for this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-catch-same-choice)