# Trigger event on re-selecting same value on mat-select

Tags: angular, typescript, events, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I'm working on a `mat-table` which implements pagination, filtering, selection, etc. I have this `mat-select` on one of the header columns which I use to set a global value for all the other `mat-select` on the same column... Like this

[image]

Everything works good so far, but lets say I choose a global value, and then I increase the `pageSize` of the table, the rows that already had the selection will stay that way, but the new additional rows will have the default value; now if I go to the global `mat-select` again and click on the same option to apply the value to the new rows, nothing will occur since I'm not actually *changing* the selection; so I'm trying to basically fire the `SelectionChange` event of the `mat-select` again even though the value is actually the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm thinking there must be a really simple way to make this work but I'm not seeing it; if any additional info is needed let me know!

Comment: any luck, i'm curious what you've come up with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I know this is late, but I've come to find a solution.*

Normally, we would be using `@Output() selectionChange` to pass the selected value to a function in our `.ts` file and do what we want there. But this doesn't work if we select the same value.

**Solution:**

So what we need to do instead is use `@Output() openedChange` which will pass `true` (opened) or `false` (closed). We are interested in when we close the mat-select component. Unfortunately openedChange doesn't have direct access to the value we selected. So we simply make a member variable which is binded to the value we select, and whenever openedChange is triggered and returns false, we will use that member variable.

Here's the basic code:

**your-component.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Options</mat-label>
  <mat-select *ngFor="let option of allOptions;"
              (openedChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"
              [(value)]="selectedVariable">
    <mat-option [value]="option">
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**your-component.component.ts**

```
  selectedVariable: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //...
  }

  onSelectionChange(opened: boolean) {
    if (!opened && this.selectedVariable) {
      // Do whatever you want here with `this.selectedVariable`
      console.log(this.selectedVariable);
    }
  }
```

**Note:** In the onSelectionChange function, you need to make sure that something was actually selected. Because otherwise the function will continue if a user clicks on the select, and clicks away from it without selecting anything.

Comment: At the end of the day if it solves the issue it might help someone else :) could you implement this in Stackblitz or similar to see it in action?

Comment: @IvanS95 I was trying to create a demo in Stackblitz, but I'm having issues with the material components (eg mat-select). Maybe if I'm feeling inspired some other time I will try again.

Comment: Thanks for this. I spent a lot of time to find this. Here is sample for someone like me. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-catch-same-choice

Comment: @jornathon Awesome, thanks for doing that. I took a quick look and seems to have the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit of a "workaround", but I wonder if you could leverage:

> @Output()
>   openedChange: EventEmitter
>
> Event emitted when the select panel has been toggled.

And fire your function any time the select is changed or closed, as I believe that is essentially what you're looking to accomplish.

However, you might have to add some logic to prevent your function from being fired twice.

Comment: I thought of that, but that event will fire everytime the panel is toggled which might not be the best approach as I want to fire the event only when clicking on the option itself, not on the combobox; in other words, I literally want the same as `selectionChange` without actually requiring to **change** the current selection

Comment: you could add or move the function to the (click) event of the mat-option ?

Comment: Hmm, that might just do, I can't find info on the `mat-option` itself in the docs; but I might tweak my function a little, will try something along those lines

Comment: If I move it to the click event of the `mat-option` it stops the column from getting the same change; seems the information I receive from that event is really different so the code I currently have stops working as intended

Comment: hmmmmmm..  maybe on change you can manually set the value to something else and then back to what it was originally, to manually trigger the change..?

Comment: any luck.  i'm curious what you came up with

Comment: wasn't able to re-call the event, it simply does not allow me to call it from another place; last thing I was trying was setting the value to `null` at the end of the function so that when I click on the same option it registers a 'change' since the value at that moment should be null, haven't tested it though

Comment: Updating, didn't work as well, doing that deletes everything from the combobox, so it displays as a line which I cannot click or anything, if not just for the functionality of it, aesthetically it looks awful :(

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Although, the proposed answers did not meet my requirements as closing the box will trigger the event, and I wanted it to trigger only when reselecting same value (not when closing the select).

I found the solution below, where I let the `<mat-option>` component directly handle the onChange Event:

```
<mat-select [value]="currentValue">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let value of values"
              [value]="value"
              (click)="onValueChange(value)">
    {{value}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

PS: Also, the other proposition rerenders slowly

Have a good one :)